# MEL XPath3 expression for attribute

Tags: mule, mule-el, xpath-3.0

I am splitting an xml document and below is a sample

```
<Row>
    <tags id="1165" name="Code_Name">pqr</tags>
    <tags id="1102" name="Source_Name">xxx</tags>
    <tags id="1176" name="Code_Value">12_M</tags>
    <tags id="1177" name="Code_Value_Description">Annual</tags>
    <tags id="1148" name="System_Control">R</tags>
    <tagi id="1169" name="Code_Instance">10278</tagi>
    <tags id="10494" name="Has_History"/>
    <tags id="10495" name="Obsolete"/>
    <tagi id="1179" name="Code_Value_Instance">1545</tagi>
    <tagi id="1168" name="Source_Number">4</tagi>
    <tags id="1106" name="Update_Date">20150821</tags>
    <tags id="944" name="Update_Source">abc</tags>
</Row>
```

I need to extract the value of id 1165. I am trying a MEL XPath3 expression and getting errors.

```
#[xpath3('/Row/tags/@id='1165'')]
```

I know `#[xpath3('/Row/tags[1]')]` works but I need select based on the attribute id.
Fragment of the flow is below.

```
        <foreach collection="xpath3('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/cmn:Response/Report/Level/Tab/*', payload, 'NODESET')" doc:name="For Each">
            <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
            <logger message="PL3  #[xpath3('/Row/tags/@id='1165'')] #[xpath3('/Row/tags[1]')]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</foreach>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Hari

Comment: After some attempts #[xpath3('/Row/tags[@id=&quot;1165&quot;]')] seems working. Could this be verified? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xpath3 is namespace-aware so you need to provide that. But you can use wildcard as below. In addition, you need to escape the single quotes.

```
xpath3('/*:Row/*:tags[@id=\'1165\']')
```

Comment: Thanks Tyrone I will try this out.